# Using the correct Join in a mySQL query

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query which joins several tables together.

None of the selected columns are nullable so what is the best type of join to use???

Here's the query:

```
SELECT ir.range_name, it.item_type, oi.itemQuantity, i.item_value
FROM orders o 
JOIN order_items oi ON oi.orderId = o.id 
JOIN items i ON i.id = oi.itemNumber
JOIN item_types it ON it.id = i.item_type
JOIN item_ranges ir ON ir.id = i.item_name
WHERE o.id = 1;
```

If I've already managed to get the correct answer please let me know!

Comment: I think inner join are always better

Comment: The best type of join, or query in general, depends what you're trying to achieve. That query looks perfectly sensible, but I have no way of knowing if it will do what you want it to.

Comment: depends on your needs -- your above query is probably what you're looking for.  inner joins are faster than outer joins.  so if this returns what you want, you're in good shape.

Comment: I'm getting the correct results with this... just wondered whether there's a more efficient way of joining.

Comment: You might want to rethink some of your column names though - e.g. why does a column called `item_name` reference a column on `item_ranges` called `id`? And some columns have_underscores but others are camelCase...

Comment: You make a very good point @IMSoP! I'm not too far in to standardise. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax that you are using is an `INNER JOIN`. This type of join returns the matching rows in each table.

That means that you would have to be sure that your `orders` has a row that matches in `order_items`, then your `order_items` row must match to `items`, etc. If it doesn't, then you will not return any rows.

So you might have to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead.  A `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows from the `orders` table even if there is not a matching row in the table that it is joined to.

```
SELECT ir.range_name, 
  it.item_type, 
  oi.itemQuantity, 
  i.item_value
FROM orders o 
LEFT JOIN order_items oi ON oi.orderId = o.id 
LEFT JOIN items i ON i.id = oi.itemNumber
LEFT JOIN item_types it ON it.id = i.item_type
LEFT JOIN item_ranges ir ON ir.id = i.item_name
WHERE o.id = 1;
```

Here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html), if you need help learning the correct syntax.

Note: You can also mix the `JOIN` types. So you could use an `INNER JOIN` between the `orders` and `order_items` but then a `LEFT JOIN` on some of the other tables. It really depends on your data and what you are trying to return as the result.

Answer (score 1):

The type of JOIN you are looking is `LEFT JOIN`.

The explain it shorter, the `INNER JOIN` only retrieves row that has atleast one matching value on the other table. If you are joining more than two tables, the row must have atleast one match on each tables in order for the record to be shown on the result list.

However, the `LEFT JOIN` displays all records on the *LeftHand Side* (*the `ORDERS` table*) table whether the records has no matching row on the other tables.

```
SELECT  ir.range_name, it.item_type, oi.itemQuantity, i.item_value
FROM    orders o 
        LEFT JOIN order_items oi ON oi.orderId = o.id 
        LEFT JOIN items i ON i.id = oi.itemNumber
        LEFT JOIN item_types it ON it.id = i.item_type
        LEFT JOIN item_ranges ir ON ir.id = i.item_name
WHERE   o.id = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*records may not the same with yours but still have the same thought*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9d63/2)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)